# Adding flurry to iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, flurry

1. In the finder, drag FlurryAnalytics/ into project's file folder. (NOTE: If you are upgrading the Flurry iOS SDK, be sure to remove any existing Flurry library folders from your project's file folder before proceeding.)
2. Now add it to your project:
   File > Add Files to “Your Project” ... > FlurryAnalytics

   - Destination: select Copy items into destination group’s folder (if needed)
     ￼￼
   - Folders: Choose 'Create groups for any added folders'

**- Add to targets: select all targets that the lib will be used for**

1. In your Application Delegate:

   - Import FlurryAnalytics and inside "applicationDidFinishLaunching:" add: [FlurryAnalytics
     startSession:@"YOUR_API_KEY"];

What exactly do you have to do for the bolded step above? I'm using xcode 4.3.3
Where do you do that step?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That means drag the FlurryAnalytics library into Xcode project view on the left, and when it comes up asking if you want to copy it or reference it, you should...

1. Copy it
2. Make sure all build targets have a check mark next to their name.

Edit:  Here is a technical, no-fun definition of build targets http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html.  Sometimes it is useful to create multiple targets.  If you don't know what they are, you likely only have one target and don't have to worry about it.